# create multiple tables in BigQuery for multiple tables in SAP HANA

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, hana

I am exporting data from SAP HANA database to my GCP Big Query Database.
My requirement is if I have multiple tables in SAP HANA, then how I can create multiple tables in Big Query.

In my current code using python, I am only able to create a single table in Big Query. Is there any way to achieve so?

```
from hdbcli import dbapi
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()


# Open database connection
conn = dbapi.connect(
    address="*******.hana.trial-***10.hanacloud.ondemand.com", 
    port=443,
    user='DBADMIN', 
    password='******')

conn.isconnected()

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("select * from demo_HANA")

result = cursor.fetchall()

df=pd.DataFrame(result,columns=["id","name"])

print(df)

table_id = "project1.test1.hanav1"


job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    
    schema=[
       
        bigquery.SchemaField("name", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.STRING),
        
    ],
    
    write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
)

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    df, table_id, job_config=job_config
)  # Make an API request.
job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.

table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print(
    "Loaded {} rows and {} columns to {}".format(
        table.num_rows, len(table.schema), table_id
    )
)
```

Comment: List the tables, iterate over them and use your code to create the table. Where is the challenge?

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere, is it possible to get a sample piece of code for it?